# How do I make streak highlights that are affected by lighting?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

Sorry about the title, it's a little hard to describe.

I'm making a toon shader for eevee, and I want to make a specular effect that looks like straight lines across the mesh. I managed to do it once using a gradient texture and a color ramp, but it wasn't affected by the lighting, which is what I want to achieve. The image here is the type of effect I'm describing.

[image]

So is there a way to do this while it is still affected by lighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this - I'm not sure what you're going for with the "movement", but this might at least get you started:

[image: CoinTurn]

Comment: Oh, and my mistake - for toon shading, ColorRamp should be set to _constant_ (I forgot to switch it).